# GridView Yii2 Вывести значения (hasMany)

Tags: php, yii2

**Controller:**

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query' => User::find()->asArray()->where(['email' => $_SESSION['auth']])->with('posts'),]);

$this->view->title = "Личный кабинет";
return $this->render('index', compact('postForm', 'users', 'dataProvider'));
```

**View:**

```
<div id="posts" class="panel-body">
            <?= GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'columns' => [
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'title',
                        'value' => function ($model) {

                        },
                        'format' => 'raw',
                    ],

                ],
            ]); ?>
        </div>
```

**Задача:**

Вывести все посты у текущего пользователя. В контроллере применяю asArray(), чтобы работать не с массивом объектов, а как с обычным. Как мне вывести все поля из таблицы posts?

**Update view:**

```
<div id="posts" class="panel-body">
            <?= GridView::widget([
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                'columns' => [
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'title',
                        'value' => function($model) {
                            $i = 0;
                            $titles = [];

                            foreach ($model['posts'] as $item) {
                                $titles[$i] = $item['title'];
                                $i++;
                            }

                            return $titles;

                        },
                        'format' => 'raw',
                    ],

                ],
            ]); ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть структуру таблиц `User` и `Posts`. А так же метод `getPosts()` со связью `hasMany()` внутри, из модели `User` (если это прописано)

Comment: Получил все заголовки. Теперь вопрос как отрендерить то массив?  

  'value' => function($model) {
                        $i = 0;
                        $titles = [];

                         foreach ($model['posts'] as $item) {
                                    $titles[$i] = $item['title'];
                                    $i++;
                          }

                          return $titles;

                  },

Comment: Возвращаю массив return $titles   с заголовками.  Я думал он внутри там сам по нему пробежит и выведет в вид , но в вид он выводит лишь строку Array ..